# Email anonymity

Tags: anonymity, tails, email

I'm using Tails on a newly formatted pc at home, conncting to internet via wifi. I need to remain anonymous to the recipients (no matters email encyption) so i wonder if it's enough to register a new account somewhere,even with javascript enabled, without supplying any personal relevant element, and using it by icedove or webmail to send emails: will my ip remain unknow to anyone or is it possible, to some degree (I won't fight against NSA :-) ) identify it and, at the end, to find me? I'm not particularly expert about this issues, so every suggestion (expecially if simple!) will be greatly appreciated. Thank you guys!

Comment: I think there still is a chance of figuring out your location. Between the ISP and the first TOR relay [Check this](https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https)

Comment: So it seems to me that the hacker or my ISP COULD see I'm using tor but not the site I'm visiting and that, at the end of the chain, someone could see everything but NOT my location that is, provided the fact that I won't give any personal information, who I am...is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 relatively easy methods to send an anonymous email. Be careful to not abuse the first method, otherwise, the service provider might decide to restrict or block global access to the service permanently. Use prudence and good judgement when sending anonymous emails. In most jurisdictions, it is a serious crime to send emails that threaten, harass, or contain illegal content. It is easy to inadvertently leave tell-tale clues in the Subject line or message body that could give away your identity. A combination of unique elements such as type of language, grammar, font, etc. have the potential to trace back to you.

Configure Tor browser ▸ Privacy and Security Settings ▸ Tor Network Settings to the highest level. In Tor browser ▸ Network Settings ▸ Enter custom bridges. Consider using the most obfuscated (most secure) type of custom [bridge](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en) address, [obfs4](https://bridges.torproject.org/options). (The only other type of bridge address that might be more secure is a private obfuscated bridge address that a trusted friend gives to you, but not to the public, after your friend sets up a [private Tor bridge relay](https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy-debian-instructions.html.en).)

Use Tor browser to connect to [StartMail](https://www.startmail.com/). Open a free 7-day trial account. Your name, phone number, email address, or other personally identifying information are not required to open the account. Configure your preferred user account settings. Send your anonymous email. The only sender IP address that will appear in the full email header will be the IP address of the StartMail email server. The email header will not include your IP address, your name, your country location, or any other personally identifying information about you.

With Tor browser, connect to [Yandex mail](https://mail.yandex.com/). Open an email account. Your name, phone number, email address, or other personally identifying information are not required to open the account. Configure your preferred user account settings. Send your anonymous email. The only sender IP address that will appear in the full email header will be the IP address of the Yandex email server. The email header will not include your IP address, your name, your country location, or any other personally identifying information about you.

The email service providers will be unable to log or record your IP address if you are using the Tor browser with the highest Privacy and Security Settings and an obfuscated bridge address.

In contrast to the [StartMail](https://www.startmail.com/) free 7-day trial account, a personal paid subscription to [StartMail](https://www.startmail.com/) email service does not provide 100% anonymity, although, to the best of my knowledge, it does provide the highest level of anonymity and privacy from a commercial email service provider that includes a built-in option to send and receive PGP encrypted emails. Additionally, StartMail [headquarters](https://www.startmail.com/privacy) are in the Netherlands, [beyond the legal jurisdiction](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/privacy-policy.html?) of any foreign governments. See StartMail [Policies](https://www.startmail.com/privacy), [Technology](https://www.startmail.com/documents/whitepaper/whitepaper.en_US.pdf), and [Privacy](https://www.startmail.com/privacy) statements for a better understanding of the practices and methods that StartMail uses to protect a user's personal information, privacy, and anonymity, including [guaranteed no tracking or advertising](https://www.startmail.com/privacy) and regular [automatic deletion](https://www.startmail.com/privacy) of some of the users' personal information within hours after the [session ends](https://www.startmail.com/privacy).

(Note: the following info about the sister Internet search engines [StartPage](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/) and [Ixquick](https://eu.ixquick.com/) does not relate directly to sending an anonymous email, but since [StartMail](https://www.startmail.com/), [StartPage](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/) and [Ixquick](https://eu.ixquick.com/) are members of of the same parent organization, [Surfboard Holding BV](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/privacy-policy.html?), Zeist, The Netherlands, it might be worth noting this info because it relates directly to Internet anonymity and privacy. The [StartPage](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/) and [Ixquick](https://eu.ixquick.com/) Internet search engines provide superior anonymity and privacy, especially if you connect to the sites with the Tor browser. The servers use advanced [SSL encryption](https://www.startpage.com/eng/about-startpage-ssl.html) for all Internet connections to the servers. The servers provide all users the [option](https://www.ixquick.com/proxy/eng/help.html?hmb=1) to establish a free, instantaneous, and [certified anonymous](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/protect-privacy-qa.html?#q16) [proxy](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/protect-privacy-qa.html?#q13) Internet connection with the server of any web site in the Internet search results. The servers [do not collect or share](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/what-makes-startpage-special.html?) any personal information. The servers do not log [legitimate](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/protect-privacy-qa.html?#q5) users' [IP addresses](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/protect-privacy-qa.html?#q3), and do not record or save users' Internet [search activities or search results](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/protect-privacy-qa.html?#q5). The search engines use the so-called [POST](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/protect-privacy-qa.html?#q17) method (instead of the GET method) to keep your search terms out of the logs of webmasters of sites that you reach from the search results. [Settings](https://eu.ixquick.com/do/preferences?language=english&language_ui=english&nj=0) gives all users the option to save a user's preferred page settings without using a cookie. The [StartPage](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/) and [Ixquick](https://eu.ixquick.com/) [server clusters](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/protect-privacy-qa.html?#q20) are in the Netherlands, Singapore, and the United States. The URL of the [referenced servers](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/protect-privacy-qa.html?#q20) herein contain the domain name [.eu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.eu), which designates the servers are in the the European Union, and, in this instance, in the Netherlands [beyond the legal jurisdiction](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/eng/privacy-policy.html?) of the NSA and any other foreign government agencies. For a better understanding of the practices and polices of [StartPage](https://s9-eu5.startpage.com/) and [Ixquick](https://eu.ixquick.com/) regarding anonymity and privacy, see [StartPage Protects Your Privacy!](https://eu.ixquick.com/eng/protect-privacy.html?), [Privacy Q&A](https://eu.ixquick.com/eng/protect-privacy-qa.html?), and [Our privacy policy](https://eu.ixquick.com/eng/privacy-policy.html?).)

Comment: If you take time to perfrom due diligence and study the aforementiond web sites, their privacy policies, their organizational infrastructure, and the location of their Internet server arrays, you will see that my statements are 100% accurate. Of course, I have had been doing that for 7 years years, and I know a little about those sites

Comment: The original answer included unintentional major mistakes and misinformation. Refer to the revised answer, which now includes corrections that set the record straight.

Comment: Seriously, can we kill this clear sales-pitch of an answer already? It's full of utter misinformation and should be purged.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work. No they will not know your true location.

However you should be careful about the content of your email, even if you use tor. If your actions clearly influence or relate to you or a small group of individuals you belong to then tor cannot protect you against people joining the dots and leaving you on a small list of possible candidates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible leak where some mail providers provide a way to figure out from which locations a certain email account was logged in.
To avoid this, you can use [Bitmessage over Tor](https://www.bitmessage.org/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_setup_Bitmessage_to_work_with_Tor) and register on mail gateways (I prefer [Mailchuck](https://mailchuck.com/)).
This way is somewhat more secure because Bitmessage itself provides some anonymity (but it is not enough so you still need Tor), then the mail gateway will know nothing about you.
However, in this approach, exploits (if any) in Bitmessage software will make it possible to find your real IP address.